# Error: Citrix Registry Patch failed to install. Reason: Access Denied

Tags: performance-testing, citrix, loadrunner

While recording a Citrix application,I got the following error log-

> Error: The Citrix Registry patch failed to installed. Reason: Access is denied.
>   You need to install the following registry patch manually:`<Loadrunner installation folder>`\dat\Enable_Citrix_API.reg. Double click the file to install the registry patch."

I have tried most fixes suggested for this error (both with the registry key and the path change fixes available online).

1st Fix - Tried didn't work

[image]

2nd Registry Path Fix-  didn't work either

[image]

Comment: Did you try running VuGen as administrator?

Comment: yes,I tinkered with registry as an administrator as well

Comment: Just a guess, but could it be a 32 bit application and you're editing the 64 bit registry? There's different path, or use the regedit under syswow64

Comment: No bro installed a 64 bit citrix receiver.I've tried syswow64 fix